# Scalameter task not being found

Tags: scala, sbt, scalameter

I'm trying to add scalameter tests to an existing project of mine. According to the docs, I can [add this code](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter-examples/blob/master/basic-with-separate-config/build.sbt) to my build.sbt and then I should be able to invoke `sbt bench:test` and have only the benchmarks run. However, when I run the command, I get this error:

```
$ sbt "bench:test"
[info] welcome to sbt 1.8.2 (N/A Java 17.0.6)
<snip>
[error] No such setting/task
[error] bench:test
[error]
```

When I list the tasks in the sbt shell, I see no sign of the bench task. How can I get this working?

I've created the benchmark file in `src/bench/scala/EndpointBenchmark.scala` in case that's important. I'm not totally sure where the test should reside.

I had a look at the sbt docs and googled the error above, but I couldn't find anything mentioning how to deal with the case where the setting/task isn't found at all. I assume I need to add it into the root project somehow?

**build.sbt**

```
val scalaVersionString = "2.13.10"

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := scalaVersionString

val AkkaVersion = "2.7.0"
val AkkaHttpVersion = "10.5.0"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "sample_project"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http" % AkkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-testkit" % AkkaHttpVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream-testkit" % AkkaVersion,
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-http-spray-json" % AkkaHttpVersion,
  "com.maximeroussy.invitrode" % "invitrode" % "2.0.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % Test,
  "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.21" % Test,
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.5"
)

lazy val Benchmark = config("bench") extend Test

/**  This allows running ScalaMeter benchmarks in separate sbt configuration.
 *  It means, that when you want run your benchmarks you should type `bench:test` in sbt console.
 */
lazy val basic = (project in file("."))
  .settings(Defaults.coreDefaultSettings ++ Seq(
    name := "sample_project_benchmarks",
    scalaVersion := scalaVersionString,
    scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature", "-Xlint"),
    publishArtifact := false,
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.storm-enroute" %% "scalameter" % "0.21" % "bench"
    ),
    resolvers ++= Seq(
      "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
      "Sonatype OSS Releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
    ),
    testFrameworks += new TestFramework("org.scalameter.ScalaMeterFramework"),
    Benchmark / parallelExecution := false,
    logBuffered := false
  )
) configs(
  Benchmark
  ) settings(
  inConfig(Benchmark)(Defaults.testSettings): _*
  )
```